# How can I call a tableview delegate methods from one class to another class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I want to perform a drop down for each cell hence I have inserted a tableview with in a cell and I am working with the expanding cell that a cell gets expanded when it clicks, so that it will show as a dropdown.

MainTableView:

```
import UIKit

class MainTableView: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!
var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
let selectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 300.0
let unselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
var name = ["red","green","blue","white"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return name.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = mainTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! mainTableViewCell
    cell.Title.text = name[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        return selectedCellHeight
    }
    return unselectedCellHeight
}
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil && selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        selectedCellIndexPath = nil
    } else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
        // This ensures, that the cell is fully visible once expanded
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .None, animated: true)
    }
}

 }
```

MainTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class MainTableViewCell:UITableViewCell,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var dropDownList: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var Title: UILabel!
var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
let selectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
let unselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
var name = ["magenta","yellow","orange","cyan","black","grey"]
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    dropDownList.delegate = self
    dropDownList.dataSource = self
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return name.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = dropDownList.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! subTableViewCell
    cell.subTitle.text = name[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        return selectedCellHeight
    }
    return unselectedCellHeight
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    /* If I select any row in subTableView then the tableview has to disappear and the height of mainTableView row should be rearranged(i.e the dropdown should dissappear) */ 

}
```

InnerTableViewCell:
    import UIKit

```
class subTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var subTitle: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

 }
```

If I call the mainTableView  delegate methods in the mainTableViewCell class  then it would be easy but I am getting struggle with this .Help me!

Comment: Use postNotification method or custom delegate methods,

Comment: I haven't read all the code but, if you want to call back to the `MainTableView`, how about giving the `MainTableViewCell` a property that gets set to `self` (i.e. the main controller) during the top level `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

First Create a delegate method to cell :-

```
  import UIKit

protocol MainTableViewCellDelegate {
    func myFunc()
}

class MainTableViewCell:UITableViewCell,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate { 

   var MainTableViewCellDelegate! = nil

  // Put Your Other code Lines


   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         delegate.myFunc()
   }
}
```

Then in your MainTableView add **MainTableViewCellDelegate** :-

```
 import UIKit

 class MainTableView: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, MainTableViewCellDelegate { 

       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cell = dropDownList.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! subTableViewCell
           cell.subTitle.text = name[indexPath.row]
           cell.delegate = self
           return cell
       }

       func myFunc() {
           self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil) //Put your segue
      }
 }
```

Comment: Will you tell how to perform dropdown using a tableview which is within the  cell of another table view?

Comment: For that you should go through with a 3rd party library or some tutorial.